# Do I Have a Trojan after Plugging in Hard Drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virus, trojan

I temporarily fixed a family member’s hard drive so I could get the data off of it onto my computer. As I was transferring over the downloads, I had a windows defender message come up detecting a Trojan. I deleted the quarantined files in windows defender. Then, windows explorer couldn’t transfer two of the files over from the downloads (I am assuming those files had a Trojan virus, or maybe they had been deleted from windows defender). I decided to skip them, and then the files transferred over to my Documents.

After thinking more about the trojan, I delete all of the files that I had transferred from the hard drive, and unplugged the hard drive.

1. Is there any chance that I have a Trojan? First of all, I never opened any of the files. But could I still have it regardless?
2. Also, if I run a windows defender scan (or any other free anti-virus per reccomenation), and nothing shows up, is there nothing to worry about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would still run malwarebytes anti-malware and a full deep Avast free edition (or premium preferably) scan on there.

Comment: If all you did was copy the files, and did not open or view them, you're *probably* safe, but as @spikey_richie states, a single scan by antimalware can't hurt. Do *not* set the additional software to scan all the time, alongside Defender, as that slows the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any chance that I have a Trojan? First of all, I never opened any of the files. But could I still have it regardless?

This is extremely unlikely. No virus that I know of can be installed by the simple
presence of a file on the computer, unless it replaces a Windows file,
which isn't your case.

The USB itself could be infected with an `autorun.inf` auto-infection virus,
but Windows 10 by default disables this infection vector, unless you have
manually enabled it. You may easily have a look at the root folder of the USB
to see if that file is present (don't open it in any way, of course).

> Also, if I run a windows defender scan (or any other free anti-virus per recommendation), and nothing shows up, is there nothing to worry about?

I wish things were that simple, but the fact that the antivirus found nothing
only means that it found nothing. To feel safer, you should run a deep scan
by Defender (you did) and a couple of other well-known antivirus products.
[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) is recommended,
and other products may have a "Home call" page for scanning without
local installation.

Use only well-known antiviruses and be alert for spoofed website names
(different by one character only from the real ones).